# Create alias of an executable binary as absolute path

Tags: bash, shell, binary, alias, executable

Considering an executable binary file `mybinaryfile`, I want to write a bash script that creates an alias `mybinary` which then allows me, after executing the script, to run the binary file regardless of its location and of the location I am when calling the binary file. Do you know how I can achieve this without writing the path to the binary to the `PATH` environnement variable ?

Thanks

Comment: If `mybinaryfile` is not in a directory that is contained in `$PATH`, then I assume that you must first search for `mybinaryfile` with `find`. See `man find`. I suggest using a function instead of an alias. See `help function`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone told me to use this (script must be in the same folder as the binary when executing it) and it works pretty fine :

```
current_path=$(pwd)
alias mybinary="$current_path/mybinaryfile"
```

Then I can finely call

```
mybinary -flag1 arg2
```

wherever I want on my terminal session